# read files without hardcoding path in python

Tags: python

I am writing a PySpark code to read PARQUET files from my local machine and process them. My directories and file paths look like this:

```
.
├── customer
│   └── day=20220815
│       └── part-00000-4dff7e82-411b-4940-bdb6-33acf5a189b4-c000.snappy.parquet
└── customer_interaction
    └── day=20220815
        └── part-00000-7b3ee7fd-c515-41c0-96a6-2f2dbbc0c9cf-c000.snappy.parquet

4 directories, 2 files
```

There are two different files in two different folders that I want to read in my code. As of now, I am using hardcoded values to pass the paths of these files like this:

```
customer_df = spark.read.parquet('customer/day=20220815/part-00000-4dff7e82-411b-4940-bdb6-33acf5a189b4-c000.snappy.parquet')
customer_interaction_df = spark.read.parquet('customer_interaction/day=20220815/part-00000-7b3ee7fd-c515-41c0-96a6-2f2dbbc0c9cf-c000.snappy.parquet')
```

But this is not what I want. Is there any other way that I can use for reading the files?

Comment: I'm not aware of the possible solutions. Could you please help?

Comment: Read all `paraquet` files into list uisng `glob` & itterate over them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `glob` module, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/ for examples.
You can also use `pathlib` which also as a glob module.

In your case, the command is:

```
import glob

# Returns a list of names in list files.
print("Using glob.glob()")
files = glob.glob('/main_directory/**/*.snappy.parquet', 
                   recursive = True)
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Comment: ```
import glob
files = glob.glob('/home/awadh/skuad_training/source/**/**/*.parquet', recursive = True)
for file in files:
    print(file)
```
I am using above code snippet but getting no output.

Comment: This is probably because the `.snappy.paraquet`, try replacing `*.paraquet` with `*.snappy.paraquet`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
X_data_no=[]
no_images = glob.glob("./Dataset/brain_tumor_dataset/no/"+'*')
for myFile in no_images:
    image_no = cv2.imread(myFile)
    print(image_no)
```